# recursive .find() returns the wrong obj

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a small issue with a recursive .find() . when I use it to find ID === 2, it returns be the object with ID === 1 ...

I have been scratching my head and I don't understand why that happens

my object is similar to this

**UPDATE:** while debugging, it does seem to finish at the right object, but the final return gives the parent of the right object, not the actual object

```js
{ID: 1,
 children: [
   {ID:2,
    children: [
      {ID:4,
       children: [...]},
    ]},
   {ID:3,
    children: [...]},
 ]}
```

```js
  findItem(ID: number, items: Agenda[] = this.getItems()){
    const foundItem = items.find(a => {
      if (ID === a.ID) {
        return a;
      } else {
        return this.findItem(ID, a.children);
      }
    })
    return foundItem;
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) will always return elements from an outer array - it only requires callback function to return `true` - doesn't matter where that `true` comes from (nested array in this case). You should use regular `for...of` if you want to traverse your nested arrays:

```js
let data = [{ID: 1,
 children: [
   {ID:2,
    children: [
      {ID:4,
       children: []},
    ]},
   {ID:3,
    children: []},
 ]}]
 
 function findItem(ID, items) {
    for(let a of items){
      if (ID === a.ID) {
        return a;
      } else {
        return findItem(ID, a.children);
      }
    }
  }
  
 console.log(findItem(2,data))
```

Comment: FYI: I needed to make some adjustments as that code didn't take into account if childrens is empty, also return findItem would return undefined if item not found, and wouldn't go to the next heading. this is the updated code `
    for (const a of agendas) {
      if (agendaID === a.meetingAgendaItemID) {
        return a;
      } else {
        if (a.children.length) {
          const item = this.findAgenda(agendaID, a.children);
          if (item) {
            return item;
          }
        }
      }
    }`